# Configure CloudWatch log monitoring for Windows server out of AWS (non-EC2 instance)

Tags: windows, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I have **MS Windows Server 2012 R2 running out of AWS** facilities and want to watch its logs by CloudWatch.

Configuring Linux server, which is not an EC2 instance, works well as there are instructions how to install agents sending log records to CloudWatch regardless of where the server runs.

However, searching for such instructions for MS Windows server I am only able to find references for EC2Config Service, e.g. here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/UsingConfig_WinAMI.html#UsingConfig_Install

It is possible, that I can simply install the service on "nonEC2" instance and it will work, but as the server is in production mode, I do not dare to do blind test ignoring risk of getting the server into problems.

Note, that **I care about watching logs written to log files**, I do not care (currently) about system log content.

It would help me if:

- someone refers to positive experience with using EC2Config service on nonEC2 server
- or someone proposes alternative method to get the log records into CloudWatch.